# How to convert this sequence to this hash?

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I'm consuming a webservice from my application in C# .net (2.0) that return values (as string) like this:

```
%23k.%0d%16%c4%8a%18%efG%28%b9c%12%b7%f1%e2%e7j%93
```

I know that the real value for that is:

```
236B2E0D16C48A18EF4728B96312B7F1E2E76A93
```

But I don't know how to convert from the returned value to the real value.

Any thoughts?

Anyway, thanks for your time.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going down the line:

If you encounter '%' copy the next two characters

Otherwise take the ascii code of the character found and output as hex

```
%23  => 23
k    => 6B
.    => 2E
%0d  => 0D
```

[ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

But in code I'm pretty sure this will work:

```
char c = 'k';
int ascii = (int)c;
string hex = ascii.ToString("X2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the info Rob. If anyone wants the full method here it is:

```
static private string convertInfoHash(string encodedHash)
{
    string convertedHash = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < encodedHash.Length; i++)
    {
        if (encodedHash[i] == '%')
        {
            convertedHash += String.Format("{0}{1}",encodedHash[i + 1],encodedHash[i + 2]);
            i += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            int ascii = (int)encodedHash[i];
            convertedHash += ascii.ToString("X2");

        }
    }

    return convertedHash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of this, but try using the System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode method

Comment: Tried, but no... Thanks anyway